# Return pointer from main

Tags: c, function, pointers

I wanted to know if it was possible to return a pointer-address from the main function in c. Here a very short example:

```
int main(){
  int i = 0;
  return &i; //won't work because of type difference and because i..
}            //.. will be deallocated.
```

So is there any way to do this?
And second: i want to do this in order to return a heap object from one program to anotherone..

Is it possible to keep the heap object alive if the called program terminates on the main() but continues running on a second thread which was started from main?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the heap is part of a program's address space you'll be out of luck. Read about shared memory or other established forms of inter process communication.

Comment: When the `main` function returns, it returns to operating system code that is not expecting a pointer. So it's not clear what you hope to accomplish by returning a pointer.

Comment: Also, in your example, `i` is an automatic variable that would (usually) reside in the stack, not the heap.

Comment: Two problems here.  First on UNIX-type systems you can only return a single unsigned byte, 0-255.  The rest of the int is used for other things (see `man 2 wait`).  Secondly, assuming you are not on an embedded system, then a pointer is a virtual address, usually a page number followed by the offset within the page.  That is meaningful only within that process.  Once the process has ended, or in another process, it is meaningless.

Comment: Where do you think you will return that address? And what should whoever called it do with it?

Comment: There are some embedded systems where the heap is a fixed memory location (although you are using the stack in your code) and it might be possible (if very dodgy).  Which type of system are you working on?

Comment: If you want to keep something running after the program exits, use `fork()` to create a new process. You can return from `main()` in the original process, and the child process will stick around.

Comment: @cdarke: If `main` returns an `int` with such an address, I'd ecommend to fire the person responsible for that signature. For a freestanding ernvironment you are free to use whatever program entry function you want, including its signature, thus you should either return a pointer (maybe `void *`) or - at least `(u)intptr_t`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Olaf - fire the person responsible.  You will need a stake, rope, some dry brushwood and a flaming torch.

Comment: @Olaf:  I agree, but I'm just saying it might be possible.  There are lots of possible things that are very bad ideas, this is one of them.  But the world of embedded programming can be very different to conventional virtual memory systems, and the compilers often do not conform to standards.

Comment: @cdarke: Unless we talk about some crappy MCUs like PIC or 8051, C compilers for embedded systems are often very compatible with at least one of the older versions of the C standard. Anyway, as bare-bone systems are freestanding environments, they are free to choose their own program entry function (it need not even be called `main`). So that is even one excuse less to use an inappropriate signature.

Comment: @Olaf:  you are right of course.  The point is that the OP would have said by now if he/she was working in such an environment.  It looks like they are just clueless about how memory works.

Comment: @cdarke: As I wrote: a freestanding implementation would be just a bonus. On a hosted like a PC, not returning the expected semantics is even worse and the compiler should warn already. But a little thought invested would also show how "useless" (I was told to be more friendly) the idea is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the answer is no.

The return value from `main()` is typically for error codes.  Data to be kept persistent after the end of the process should be communicated in some other way.  When you return from `main()`, your process (and all its threads) has ended.  The memory space allocated by the operating system for the process has also been freed.  This includes your heap memory.  In short, once the process is over, there is no heap, and your object in the heap is gone.

You seem to have discovered the difficulty of inter-process communication.  There are many possible techniques to allow one process to communicate with another.  *Some* of them are

- storing data to a file
- [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)
- [message passing interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (MPI)
- [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)

Some techniques are better suited for different situations, this is why there are multiple options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did already check out an implementation of shared memory in c. Let's see what it yields..

Comment: Be careful with shared memory.  It stays persistent until something cleans it up. If your program crashes, it's still lingering around in the system.  This is unlike your heap memory which gets purged regardless of how your process ends (even if it crashes).  With greater power comes greater responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to keep the heap object alive if the called program terminates on the `main()` but continues running on a second thread which was started from `main`?

No, it is not. When you return from `main`, it is equivalent to calling `exit`. Hence, the program terminates. No threads can be alive after that.

From the C99 Standard:

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> 1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return it in a strictly-conforming program nor on most implementations.
From the C11 standard draft N1570, §5.1.2.2.1:

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. [...] It shall
>   be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters [...]:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> [...] or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Mangling the pointer into an `int` would be possible but that would be implementation-defined, possibly undefined, and... nasty.

> Is it possible to keep the heap object alive if the called program
>   terminates on the `main()` but continues running on a second thread
>   which was started from `main`?

A program is process. `main` runs in a thread. Heap memory is shared between all threads, so yes, sharing heap memory between threads is entirely possible.
However, `main` returning is equivalent to the program terminating, so you need to find another way to share it between threads. An example would be to set a pointer pointing to heap memory in one thread (maybe make that thread yield), and use that pointer in the other threads.

> i want to do this in order to return a heap object from one program to
>   anotherone..

What now, between processes or threads? Heap memory is shared between threads but **not** between multiple processes. Sharing between multiple processes is done using *shared memory* (`mmap` or `shmopen`, `shmget`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. When `main` returns, `i` ceases to exist; any pointer value you returned would be invalid.
2. I am not aware of any runtime environment that expects to receive a *pointer* value from any executed program; `main` returns an `int` because the runtime environment expects an `int`.